# Eye icon inside input password to show password

Tags: lightning-inputfield

I'm very newbie in salesforce.
I have some task to show eyeicon in form input password to show password

Is that possible to create Eye icon in input type password instead using lightning:input or other else component?

This is my snippet code

```
<div class="formControl clearfix" style='height:50px'>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="{!$Label.LabelPassword}" style="width:100%" autocomplete="off"/>                
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code with script and that should work. Replace Lead.text__c field with the required field of your choice. Also vote for the answer :-)

```
<script>function myFunction() {  var x = document.getElementById("PassId");  if (x.type === "password") {
x.type = "text";  } else {
x.type = "password";  }}</script> Enter Password : <input id="PassId" Required="True"  type="text"  onchange="document.getElementById('{!$Component.PassId}').value = this.value;" onclick="myFunction()" />  <apex:inputHidden value="{!Lead.text__c}" id="PassId" /><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lightning design system you can use input with icons.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
        <svg class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search"></use>
        </svg>
       <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" placeholder="Placeholder Text" class="slds-input" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Check SLDS guide:

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#With-Icons